# How to select one in include expression?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have a query like this:

```
return db.Tanks
        .Include(i => i.FluedLevelSensor)
        .Include(i => i.WaterLevelSensor)
        .Include(i => i.GasPressureSensor)
        .Include(i => i.HudrostaticPressureSensor)
        .Include(i => i.TechnologicalMaps)
        .Include(i => i.TechnologicalGroup)
        .Include(i => i.TemperatureSensor).ThenInclude(t => t.TemperatureSensorPoints)
        .Include(i => i.Material)
        .Include(i => i.TankType)
        .Include(i => i.QualityPassports).ThenInclude(i1 => i1.ContentType)
        .Include(i=>i.CalibrationTableNew)
        .Include(i => i.TankOperations)
        .Include(i => i.TankStates).ThenInclude(i => i.State);
```

How can I write it like this:

```
return db.Tanks
     .Include(i => i.FluedLevelSensor)
     .Include(i => i.WaterLevelSensor)
     .Include(i => i.GasPressureSensor)
     .Include(i => i.HudrostaticPressureSensor)
     .Include(i => i.TechnologicalMaps.OrderByDescending(o=>o.InsertTime).FirstOrDefault())
     .Include(i => i.TechnologicalGroup)
     .Include(i => i.TemperatureSensor).ThenInclude(t => t.TemperatureSensorPoints)
     .Include(i => i.Material)
     .Include(i => i.TankType)
     .Include(i => i.QualityPassports.OrderByDescending(o => o.SamplingDate).FirstOrDefault()).ThenInclude(i1 => i1.ContentType)
     .Include(i=>i.CalibrationTableNew)
     .Include(i => i.TankOperations.OrderByDescending(o => o.OperationStartTime).FirstOrDefault())
     .Include(i => i.TankStates.OrderByDescending(o => o.Time).FirstOrDefault()).ThenInclude(i => i.State);
```

and are there any other ways to optimize the query?

Comment: Wouldn't it just be easier to disable lazy loading for this context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you cannot enable eager-loading, you can leverage that anything *selected* is by definition *included*.

*Note:* the SQL that's emitted by the entity framework may be the same:

```
return db.Tanks.Select(i => new { 
    /* single easy value */
    Material = i.Material,

    /* for collections, select again */
    TankStates = i.TankStates.OrderByDescending(s => s.Time).ToList(),

    /* ... and so on */
});
```